# php code to match column values using if esle

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table...

**holidaymaster**

```
  id   holidaydate  cityid
   1    18-04-2015    9
```

**receiptentry table**

```
 id     coupondate     cityname   customer
 1       15-04-2015       9         A
 2       16-04-2015       9         B
 3       17-04-2015       9         C
 4       19-04-2015       9         D
```

i need to fetch data from both table by joining this...

and need to check if holidaydate not blank in holidaymaster...then echo null against this date else echo 1.

**expected output**

```
customer     coupondate    Type 
 A           15-04-2015    1 
 B           16-04-2015    1
 C           17-04-2015    1
 NULL        NULL          NULL
 D           19-04-2015    1
```

**In abov ex** - 18-04-2015 is availble in holidaymaster so i need to display null on this..else display 1.

plz help me how to join this two table and match rows...

and if joining is not possible then how to match with two different query using if else..

below is my code..

i try with 2 diff query..

```
$data = $database->getRows("SELECT RE.* FROM receipt_entry RE LEFT JOIN city_master CM ON RE.city_name = CM.id WHERE CM.cityname = :cityname
        AND str_to_date(RE.coupondate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(RE.coupondate,'%d-%m-%Y') ASC",
        array(':fromdate'=>$formdate_sql,':todate'=>$todate_sql,':cityname'=>$cityname));

        $holiday = $database->getRows("SELECT HM.holidaydate from holidaymaster HM LEFT JOIN city_master CM ON HM.cityid = CM.id WHERE CM.cityname = :cityname
        AND str_to_date(HM.holidaydate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate",array(':fromdate'=>$formdate_sql,':todate'=>$todate_sql,':cityname'=>$cityname)); 



<?php  if (is_array($data)) { foreach($data as $row)    {   ?>

<?php foreach($holiday as $row1)    {   ?>

<?php if($row['coupondate'] == $row1['holidaydate']) {  ?>
        <td>-</td>
        <?php }  else { ?>
        <td>1</td>
        <?php } ?>      

        <?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    customer, coupondate, IF(holidaydate is null, null, 1) AS type
FROM holidaymaster h
JOIN receiptentry r ON h.cityid = r.cityname
;
```